# How to create a ring communication between threads using mpsc channels?

Tags: multithreading, rust, channel

I want to spawn n threads with the ability to communicate to other threads in a ring topology, e.g. thread 0 can send messages to thread 1, thread 1 to thread 2, etc. and thread n to thread 0.

This is an example of what I want to achieve with n=3:

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender};
use std::thread;

let (tx0, rx0): (Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>) = mpsc::channel();
let (tx1, rx1): (Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>) = mpsc::channel();
let (tx2, rx2): (Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>) = mpsc::channel();

let child0 = thread::spawn(move || {
    tx0.send(0).unwrap();
    println!("thread 0 sent: 0");
    println!("thread 0 recv: {:?}", rx2.recv().unwrap());
});
let child1 = thread::spawn(move || {
    tx1.send(1).unwrap();
    println!("thread 1 sent: 1");
    println!("thread 1 recv: {:?}", rx0.recv().unwrap());
});
let child2 = thread::spawn(move || {
    tx2.send(2).unwrap();
    println!("thread 2 sent: 2");
    println!("thread 2 recv: {:?}", rx1.recv().unwrap());
});

child0.join();
child1.join();
child2.join();
```

Here I create channels in a loop, store them in a vector, reorder the senders, store them in a new vector and then spawn threads each with their own Sender-Receiver (tx1/rx0, tx2/rx1, etc.) pair.

```rust
const NTHREADS: usize = 8;

// create n channels
let channels: Vec<(Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>)> =
    (0..NTHREADS).into_iter().map(|_| mpsc::channel()).collect();

// switch tupel entries for the senders to create ring topology
let mut channels_ring: Vec<(Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>)> = (0..NTHREADS)
    .into_iter()
    .map(|i| {
        (
            channels[if i < channels.len() - 1 { i + 1 } else { 0 }].0,
            channels[i].1,
        )
    })
    .collect();

let mut children = Vec::new();
for i in 0..NTHREADS {
    let (tx, rx) = channels_ring.remove(i);

    let child = thread::spawn(move || {
        tx.send(i).unwrap();
        println!("thread {} sent: {}", i, i);
        println!("thread {} recv: {:?}", i, rx.recv().unwrap());
    });

    children.push(child);
}

for child in children {
    let _ = child.join();
}
```

This doesn't work, because Sender cannot be copied to create a new vector.
However, if I use refs (**&** Sender):

```rust
let mut channels_ring: Vec<(&Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>)> = (0..NTHREADS)
    .into_iter()
    .map(|i| {
        (
            &channels[if i < channels.len() - 1 { i + 1 } else { 0 }].0,
            channels[i].1,
        )
    })
    .collect();
```

I cannot spawn the threads, because `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<i32>` cannot be shared between threads safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This doesn't work, because Sender cannot be copied to create a new vector. However, if I use refs (& Sender):

While it's true that `Sender` cannot be copied, it does implement `Clone`, so you can always clone it manually. But that approach won't work for `Receiver`, which is not `Clone` and which you also need to extract from the vector.

The problem with your first code is that you cannot use `let foo = vec[i]` to move just one value out of a vector of non-`Copy` values. That would leave the vector in an invalid state, with one element invalid, subsequent access to which would cause undefined behavior. For this to work, `Vec` would need to track which elements were moved and which not, which would impose a cost on all `Vec`s. So instead, `Vec` disallows moving an element out of it, leaving it to the user to track moves.

A simple way to move a value out of `Vec` is to replace `Vec<T>` with `Vec<Option<T>>` and use [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take). `foo = vec[i]` is replaced with `foo = vec[i].take().unwrap()`, which moves the `T` value from the option in `vec[i]` (while asserting that it's not `None`) and leaves `None`, a valid variant of `Option<T>`, in the vector. Here is your first attempt modified in that manner ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12a1d55ee79fbe78f27e84c50649c3c2)):

```
const NTHREADS: usize = 8;

let channels_ring: Vec<_> = {
    let mut channels: Vec<_> = (0..NTHREADS)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|_| {
            let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
            (Some(tx), Some(rx))
        })
        .collect();

    (0..NTHREADS)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|rxpos| {
            let txpos = if rxpos < NTHREADS - 1 { rxpos + 1 } else { 0 };
            (
                channels[txpos].0.take().unwrap(),
                channels[rxpos].1.take().unwrap(),
            )
        })
        .collect()
};

let children: Vec<_> = channels_ring
    .into_iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(i, (tx, rx))| {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            tx.send(i as i32).unwrap();
            println!("thread {} sent: {}", i, i);
            println!("thread {} recv: {:?}", i, rx.recv().unwrap());
        })
    })
    .collect();

for child in children {
    child.join().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: I like this answer since using smart pointers is closer to my initial post than Peter's answer. However, I like the elegance of Peter's approach more. Although you answered first, is it okay if I accept Peter's answer?

Comment: @jhscheer Of course, the choice of which answer to accept is entirely up to you as the author of the question regardless of the order in which they arrive. I left my answer because it actually provides a different solution which might come useful to future readers who tackle the same issue in scenarios which Peter's approach doesn't cover.

Comment: @jhscheer Also note that there are no smart pointers in my answer, just `Option` which is much cheaper because it doesn't introduce new allocation or indirection. In [this case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=910d43f26befc94157c74f5db86fd21b) it doesn't even make the vector bigger because Rust [optimizes enums for space](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7ecic4/a_massive_refactoring_of_memory_layouts_has/) whereever possible.

Comment: @jhscheer Upvoting and accepting an answer are not the same thing. You can upvote this answer too if it helped you.

Comment: On second thought, even though I ended up using Peter's idea, I'm going to accept this answer. Because it is i) closer to my original approach and ii) helped me to better understand why my initial code fails and how to solve similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 7):

`Sender`s and `Receiver`s cannot be shared so you need to *move* them into their respective threads. That means removing them from the `Vec` or else consuming the `Vec` while iterating it - the vector is not permitted to be  in an invalid state (with holes), even as an intermediate step. Iterating over the vectors with `into_iter` will achieve that by consuming them.

A little trick you can use to get the the senders and receivers to pair up in a cycle, is to create two vectors; one of senders and one of receivers; and then rotate one so that the same index into each vector will give you the pairs you want.

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    const NTHREADS: usize = 8;

    // create n channels
    let (mut senders, receivers): (Vec<Sender<i32>>, Vec<Receiver<i32>>) =
        (0..NTHREADS).into_iter().map(|_| mpsc::channel()).unzip();

    // move the first sender to the back
    senders.rotate_left(1);

    let children: Vec<_> = senders
        .into_iter()
        .zip(receivers.into_iter())
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, (tx, rx))| {
            thread::spawn(move || {
                tx.send(i as i32).unwrap();
                println!("thread {} sent: {}", i, i);
                println!("thread {} recv: {:?}", i, rx.recv().unwrap());
            })
        })
        .collect();

    for child in children {
        let _ = child.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful answer. You might also want to construct `children` using `collect` as done in my answer.

Comment: Yeah that would be better. I'll leave it though, rather than change too much from OP's original code.

Comment: Ok, actually it's going to bug me now, so I have to change it ;)

Comment: I thought it'd make sense since you (rightfully) eliminated most of the OP's code, but it's up to you. :)

Comment: I like your neat trick with using two vectors, then rotating one and then zipping them back together. It is avoiding my initial problem with copying entries from one vector to another. However, your answer is doing the linking of the threads in reverse order to what I intended. Changing `rotate_right` to `rotate_left` solves this. (also I think you forgot to omit the child variable in your edit)

Comment: @jhscheer changed it :)