# Creating n threads that can communicate with each other

Tags: rust

I am a bit new to Rust and I am trying to simulate a network.
To do so, I want to create n threads which can communicate with each other and I can't manage to do so. I could not find a solution online so I am asking here.
I tried this code :

```rs
fn initialize_processes( nb_process : u32, main_transmitter : &Sender<Message>, main_receiver : &Receiver<Message>)
{
    let (senders, receivers): (Vec<Sender<Message>>, Vec<Receiver<Message>>) =
        (0..nb_process).into_iter().map(|_| mpsc::channel()).unzip();
    
    for i in 0..nb_process
    {

        thread::spawn(move ||
            {

                let thread_senders = senders;
                let thread_receiver =   match receivers.get(i as usize) {
                    None => panic!("Something went wrong in the initialization!"),
                    Some(x) => x,
                };
                
                let main_sender = main_transmitter;
                
                main_transmitter.send(Message{
                    transaction: Transaction {
                        seq_id: 0,
                        sender_id: 0,
                        receiver_id: 0,
                        amount: 0
                    },
                    dependencies: vec![],
                    message_type: 0
                });
                loop {
                    // Do something...
                    
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
                }
            });
    }

}
```

But I am getting the error:

```rs
error[E0277]: `Sender<Message>` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:34:9
    |
34  |         thread::spawn(move ||
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Sender<Message>` cannot be shared between threads safely
```

I think I am not understanding everything correctly. How should it be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a ring communication between threads using mpsc channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62249889/how-to-create-a-ring-communication-between-threads-using-mpsc-channels)

Comment: The senders and receivers in the vectors `senders` and `receivers` still need to be split and consumed so that each thread receives one of them each. The closure cannot just get the whole `senders` or `receivers`. For this case, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62250694) on how `senders` is consumed (via `into_iter()`).

Comment: Note also that a network might be better represented as multi-producer multi-consumer (MPMC) channels, rather than as MPSC channels.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am going to have a look at this post and read again the chapter on ownership.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `main_transmitter` in thread lambda, so each time you try to 'move' things that are not there anymore. The same applies with `main_transmitter` and `thread_senders` - I think you can move them outside the lambda and clone them.

Your corrected code would be something like:

```rust
fn initialize_processes(
    nb_process: u32,
    main_transmitter: &Sender<Message>,
    main_receiver: &Receiver<Message>,
) {
    let (senders, receivers): (Vec<Sender<Message>>, Vec<Receiver<Message>>) =
        (0..nb_process).into_iter().map(|_| mpsc::channel()).unzip();

    for i in 0..nb_process {
        let main_transmitter = main_transmitter.clone();

        let thread_senders = senders.clone();
        let thread_receiver = match receivers.get(i as usize) {
            None => panic!("Something went wrong in the initialization!"),
            Some(x) => x.clone(),
        };

        thread::spawn(move || {
            main_transmitter.send(Message {
                transaction: Transaction {
                    seq_id: 0,
                    sender_id: 0,
                    receiver_id: 0,
                    amount: 0,
                },
                dependencies: vec![],
                message_type: 0,
            });
            loop {
                // Do something...

                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure to understand how Rust ownership system works - you can read more about it [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html)

Comment: Thank you! I am in fact having a hard time fully grasping this ownership concept but I will try harder ;) I tried your code but when I try using the `thread_receiver` in the loop  I get an ownership issue ( I just added `let mut message = thread_receiver.recv().unwrap();` at the start of the loop). This time I really don't understand why I have this ownership problem because the thread receiver was cloned... 
Thank you again for your help